# How to move/position DIV container by changing CSS values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got two div containers as blocks with some fixed width and maybe height and `display: block;`

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

When you hover your mouse over container `.one` I need somehow to apply `margin-top` (or `padding-top`) to container `.two` so it moves couple pixels below while mouse is over `.one` and when you move mouse pointer aside, `.two` comes back to it's original position.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use JS? It can be done with simple CSS.

Comment: `.one:hover ~ .two{ margin-top:10px;}` try using CSS it has simple solution if `~` is no getting use try `+` used to select adjacent elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.one:hover + .two
 {
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
```

second div must be followed by first div

```
.one:hover ~ .two
 {
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
```

If some other element present between one and two, try this.

Answer (score 0):

For your javascript (jQuery) solution:

```
$( ".one" ).hover(
  function() {
     $('.two').css('marginTop', '5px');
 }, function() {
     $('.two').css('marginTop', '0');
 });
```

For smoother movement:

```
$( ".one" ).hover(
  function() {
     $('.two').animate({
         marginTop: "5px"
      }, 500 );
 }, function() {
     $('.two').animate({
         marginTop: "0"
      }, 500 );
 });
```

**Added a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epLu5e6f/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. But I already selected user3801433 as answer because it actually works. I didn't know there's CSS solution and it's way less complicated than JS.

Comment: you're welcome. A pure css-solution is indeed more effective. I let that stand here for other, who are seeking ;-)